# hiding gridview after reloading the webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net

how can we clear the gridview when we click reload this page in browser in page load i used but this did not worked for me my requirement is after uploading to gridview if i click on reload this page my gridview should be disappeared again when i select a file it should be again uploaded how can i do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//on page load

```
MyGridView.Visible= false;
```

and use on selected file

```
MyGridView.Visible= true;
MyGridView.Datasource = fileData;
MyGridView.Databind();
```

Comment: can you tell me what is that file data

Comment: file data is  your data in Table dset.Tables[0];

Comment: i had done that but it didn't worked for me i posted my code now can you check it

Comment: on page load use this it is not in your code 

MyGridView.Visible= false;

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the browser reload/refresh button you will lose the state of the page. Rather add a "Refresh" button to the page so you can manage the state of the page. Alternatively, just add code to run when the file is uploaded such as:

```
//As soon as the file is uploaded successfully
MyGridView.Enabled = false;
//Do other gridview processing here
```